# How to set or inject an arbitrary file list of environment variables in an Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-tasks

I'm porting some Jenkins builds to Azure Pipelines. One of the port sets involves an arbitrary list of environment variables that constantly changes. In Jenkins I just run an injection script to run on a list file that is within the code base's source and the build references those variables in whatever scripts or build-steps need them. Some of the variables are hard-coded while others reference environment variables of the build itself.

I looked at the [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) documentation but it either doesn't show a way to accomplish this, or I somehow missed it. How do I go about doing this besides resorting to something like `Setx` ? I have no way of knowing which build will use which variables so hard-coding them is pointless. The only constant is, I know to look for a root-level file called `env-vars.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an Azure Pipelines build Task module available on the VS Marketplace that can do this called **Json to Variable**, by Jeff Przylucki. I can either request the repo's devs to update their env-vars.txt into a JSON or run an existing tool to convert Key=Value pairs to JSONs.

> Task that will **read a JSON file** present on your build agent, from a build or a release, and will **Generate Build/Release Variables to be used in other steps**.

Json to Variable: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OneLuckiDev.json2variable

Answer (score 1):

You can use the logging commands to use job-scope variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash.

Then use them in your steps: [Environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables)

> System and user-defined variables also get injected as environment
> variables for your platform. When variables are turned into
> environment variables, variable names become uppercase, and periods
> turn into underscores. For example, the variable name any.variable
> becomes the variable name $ANY_VARIABLE.

Example:

- Step 1

  ```
   - powershell: |
       Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=my.var1]var value 1"
       Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=my.var2]var value 2"
       Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=my.var3]var value 3"
       Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=my.var4]var value 4"
     displayName: 'Set vars'
  ```

'

- Step 2

  ```
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "Var1:" $Env:MY_VAR1
      Write-Host "Var2:" $Env:MY_VAR2
      Write-Host "Var3:" $Env:MY_VAR3
      Write-Host "Var4:" $Env:MY_VAR4
    displayName: 'Read vars'
  ```

The result of step 2

[image]

Comment: This is a decent answer to start the process. It doesn't actually address the challenge stated but it is nonetheless a good place to start breaking ground.

Answer (score 0):

> The only constant is, I know to look for a root-level file called env-vars.txt

Assuming this is just a list of key:value pairs, you can read them in something like this.

If you don't want to touch the format of the file you could parse it as per @shamrai-aleksander answer and set the variables that way.

```
variables:
- template: env-vars.yml
```

env-vars.yml

```
variables:
somevariable:value
```